# Call component function from dom generated element - angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I want to create a dynamic number of html dom element buttons and have them be able to call a service when clicked. Is there any way to do that?

For example, test.component.ts:

```
import {ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
...
export class test implement OnInit(){
    constructor(private apiGet : ApiService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        ...
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            var row = document.getElementById('row');
            var cell = insertCell();
            cell.innerHTML = "<button name='" + i + '" (click)=test.callService()>click me</button>";
        }
    }
    public callService() {
        //call ApiService here using buttons name
    }
}
```

I've been getting it to work when I put the (click) event on an html element inside test.component.html, but it hasn't been working for the dom generated buttons. Is there something I'm missing, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To dynamically generate elements consider using [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, event handlers have to be defined using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method. Also you could manually trigger change detection to make sure the elements are generated in DOM. Try the following

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
...
export class test implement OnInit {
  constructor(private apiGet: ApiService, private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      var row = document.getElementById('row');
      var cell = insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = "<button id='button" + i + "' name='" + i + '">click me</button>";
    }
    this.addEventListeners(x);
  }

  private addEventListeners(x) {
    this._cdr.detectChanges();    // <-- manually trigger change detection to be sure
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      const button = document.getElementById('button' + i);
      if (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', this.callService());
      }
    }
  }

  public callService() {
      //call ApiService here using buttons name
  }
}
```

Also unrelated, `export class test implement OnInit(){` should be replaced with `export class test implement OnInit {`. The parentheses are not required here.

Comment: it doesn't seem pretty though

Answer (score 0):

Your html using `ngFor`

```
 <div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
     <button (click)="callService(button.name)">{{button.name}}</button>
 </div>
```

And your component:

```
  buttons = [
    {
      name: 'one'
    },
    {
      name: 'two'
    }
  ];

  callService(buttonName) {
    alert(`call ApiService here using buttons name: [${buttonName}]`);
  }
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pe3scn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).